# How can a block go to the middle of a grid?

Tags: html, css, web, frameworks, web-frontend

My code has a grid inside a grid on the css, the grid(that is inside) needs to be at the horizontal center of the grid in which it is contained. The problem here is that this block(grid) appears on the upper left side of the grid when it should be at the middle part. How can I achieve this process?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper .user-profile {
  padding: 40px;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.user-header {
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.user-header .grid-header {
  width: 46%;
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50% 20% 80%;
  grid-gap: .2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.grid-header-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-header-items:nth-child(10) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 4;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="user-profile">
    <div class="user-header">
      <div class="grid-header">
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
        <div class="grid-header-item">Hey</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have any questions please let me know in the comments below;)

Comment: You asked this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419782/align-items-to-the-center-of-a-grid-css Also, looks like horizontally centered. Does not appears on the upper left.

Comment: @dgknca thats the problem

Comment: @dgknca why does the code doesnt render like that on my server?

Comment: Needs debugging details. I can't know it.

Comment: ohh ok let me do that right now, thankyou